# Putting EXPLAIN results into a table?

Tags: postgresql

I see from the [Postgres 8.1 docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-explain.html) that `EXPLAIN` generated something like tabular data:

> Prior to PostgreSQL 7.3, the plan was emitted in the form of a NOTICE
>   message. Now it appears as a query result (formatted like a table with
>   a single text column).

I'm working with 9.0, for which, the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-explain.html) say, the output can be a variety of types, including TEXT and XML. What I'd really like to do is treat the output as a standard query result so that I could generate a simple report for a query or a set of queries, e.g.,

```
SELECT maxcost FROM (
    EXPLAIN VERBOSE 
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM Mytable
     WHERE value>17);
```

The above doesn't work in any form that I've tried, and I made up the attribute `maxcost` to demonstrate how neat it would be to pull out specific bits of data (in this case, the maximum estimated cost of the query). Is there anything I can do that would get me part of the way there? I'd prefer to be able to work within a simple SQL console.

Comment: Your quote from the docs shows the problem: "formatted like a table *with a single text column*".

Comment: @johnFlatness: can you elaborate, or supply an answer? Why should a single-column table be a problem? `SELECT * FROM EXPLAIN ...` could still work in such a circumstance, no? My example projecting on an attribute was just a desire, not a requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No other answers so far, so here's my own stab at it.

It's possible to read the results of explain into a variable within plpgsql, and since the output can be in XML one can wrap `EXPLAIN` in a stored function to yield the top-level costs using xpath:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION estimate_cost(IN query text, 
OUT startup numeric,
OUT totalcost numeric, 
OUT planrows numeric, 
OUT planwidth numeric)
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    query_explain  text;
    explanation       xml;
    nsarray text[][];
BEGIN
nsarray := ARRAY[ARRAY['x', 'http://www.postgresql.org/2009/explain']];
query_explain :=e'EXPLAIN(FORMAT XML) ' || query;
EXECUTE query_explain INTO explanation;
startup := (xpath('/x:explain/x:Query/x:Plan/x:Startup-Cost/text()', explanation, nsarray))[1];
totalcost := (xpath('/x:explain/x:Query/x:Plan/x:Total-Cost/text()', explanation, nsarray))[1];
planrows := (xpath('/x:explain/x:Query/x:Plan/x:Plan-Rows/text()', explanation, nsarray))[1];
planwidth := (xpath('/x:explain/x:Query/x:Plan/x:Plan-Width/text()', explanation, nsarray))[1];
RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Hence the example from the question becomes:

```
SELECT totalcost
FROM estimate_cost('SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM Mytable
     WHERE value>17');
```

Answer (score 1):

[This message](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/fhs7n9$2ok2$1@news.hub.org) suggests using "FOR rec IN EXECUTE EXPLAIN..." which seems to do the trick e.g.:

```
drop table if exists temp_a;
create temp table temp_a
(
    "QUERY PLAN" text
);


DO
$$
DECLARE
rec record;
BEGIN

FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'EXPLAIN VERBOSE select version()' 
LOOP
--  RAISE NOTICE 'rec=%', row_to_json(rec);

    insert into temp_a
    select rec."QUERY PLAN";
END LOOP;

END
$$ language plpgsql;

select *
from temp_a;
```

Comment: Interesting. That's quite an old post (8 years ago) so I think the format of `EXPLAIN` output has changed since then.

Comment: @beldaz: the format might have changed, but `explain` still returns a list of strings and this should work just fine.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks for the clarification. The explanation of "list of strings" is also helpful. So close to being a typical single-column relation format, yet not quite close enough to be trivial to handle.

Comment: For any automatic processing you should use the XML (or JSON) formats - as you have done in your answer